# How to reverse alphabetical order

Tags: python

I'm trying to make the names descend from z-a.
I'm trying to sort the list in reverse alphabetical order and then loop through the entire list to print each celebrity's name on its own line

```
def main():
   print('Celebrities  known by one name:')
   drake = ['Drake']
   BE = ['Beyonce']
   RI = ['Rihanna']
   BO = ['Bono']
   print('Drake','Beyonce','Rihanna', 'Bono')
   a = input('Enter another one name celebrity ')
   b = input('Enter another one name celebrity ')
   c = input('Enter another one name celebrity ')
   d = [a,b,c,drake,BE,RI,BO]
   f = reversed(d)
   print('Celebrities in Reverse Alpha Order')
   for d in f:
      print(d)
main()
```

So far I'm getting is this

```
['Bono']
['Rihanna']
['Beyonce']
['Drake']
Eminem
Adele
Pink
```

Its suppose to look like

```
Celebrities  known by one name:
Drake Beyonce Rihanna Bono
Enter another one name celebrity Adele
Enter another one name celebrity Eminem
Enter another one name celebrity Pink
Celebrities in Reverse Alpha Order
Rihanna
Pink
Eminem
Drake
Bono
Beyonce
Adele
```

Comment: first you're putting lists & strings in the same list, second you're not sorting the list but just reversing it...

Comment: `y = print('Drake','Beyonce','Rihanna', 'Bono')` should throw some kind of error, shouldn't it?

Comment: What is the `y` variable for? `print` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Abdou `print()` returns `None`, so it prints the names and then does `y = None`. No error, just a useless assignment.

Comment: you want `f = sorted(d,reverse=True)`. But that won't work with your input. Drop the list of 1 string...

Comment: Also write the `expected output` in post.

Comment: @Barmar, that seems to be true in python 3 but not in 2.

Comment: @Abdou Since it's calling `print()` as a function, it looks like Python 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can user `sorted..reverse` as per [doc](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort)

```
def main():
   print('Celebrities  known by one name:')
   drake = ['Drake']
   BE = ['Beyonce']
   RI = ['Rihanna']
   BO = ['Bono']

   a = input('Enter another one name celebrity ')
   b = input('Enter another one name celebrity ')
   c = input('Enter another one name celebrity ')
   d = [a,b,c,drake,BE,RI,BO]
   f = sorted(d,reverse=True)
   print('Celebrities in Reverse Alpha Order')
   for d in f:
      print(d)
main()
```

Comment: You should change to: **f = sorted(d, key=str.lower,reverse=True)**

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
l = ['Bono', 'Rihanna', 'Beyonce', 'Drake', 'eminem', 'adele', 'pink']
import string
final_list = sorted(l, key=lambda x:26 - string.ascii_lowercase.index(x[0].lower()))
```

Output:

```
['Rihanna', 'pink', 'eminem', 'Drake', 'Bono', 'Beyonce', 'adele']
```

Comment: This is a cool approach. And you can simplify it by removing the `26` constant (which is the same for all) and by using the `ord` function to get the ascii value directly: `sorted(l, key=lambda s: -ord(s[0].lower()))`. And you can get it to use all of the letters by using a list as the key: `sorted(l, key=lambda s: [-ord(c) for c in s.lower()])`

Answer (score 0):

pythons inbuilt sorting function has a `reverse` parameter, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting :

> Ascending and Descending
>
> Both `list.sort()` and `sorted()` accept a reverse parameter with a
>   boolean value. This is using to flag descending sorts. For example, to
>   get the student data in reverse age order:

```
sorted(student_tuples, key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True) [('john', 'A', 15), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('dave', 'B', 10)]

sorted(student_objects, key=attrgetter('age'), reverse=True) [('john', 'A', 15), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('dave', 'B', 10)]
```

in [Python reverse alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529641/python-reverse-alphabetical-order) is code example

Answer (score 0):

We can use:

```
names = sorted(names, key=str.lower,reverse=True)
```

Full example:

```
def main():
    print('Celebrities  known by one name:')
    names = ['Drake','Beyonce','Rihanna','Bono']
    print(" ".join(names))
    for _ in range(3):
        names.append(input('Enter another one name celebrity '))
    names = sorted(names, key=str.lower,reverse=True)
    print('Celebrities in Reverse Alpha Order')
    for name in names:
        print(name)

main()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def names(name_list):

    name_list.sort()

    **name_list.reverse()**

    return(name_list)
```

Comment: Please don't post just the code. Add some comments.