# How can I get the next string, in alphabetical DESCENDING order, in Python?

Tags: python, string, sorting

I need a simple python program that looks for a string in a list and if it doesn't find it generates the next one in **alphabetical DESCENDING ORDER**
.By that, I meant if it does not find **'abz'** it will generate **ac** deleting the last char when it reaches *'z'*.

Another example:

I have a list like: 
list = ['allena', 'allend','alphosis','alpinist', 'alternative']

**Assuming I don't know what is in the list.**

After the function find **allend** in the list it will check for **allene** to **allenz**, and after **alleo** to **allez** and after **alle** to **allz**
... Thereby by removing the last char in the string everytime it is **'z'**.... the function will reach **alp** and **alt**... until it reaches **a**

The function will change the last character of a string and remove it when it becomes **'z'** until it remains the first char only.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python reverse alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529641/python-reverse-alphabetical-order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a generator function!

```
def mygenerator(word):
  while len(word) > 0:
    lastletter = word[-1].lower()    # get last letter
    word = word[0:-1]                # remove last letter
    for lv in range(ord(lastletter), ord('z')+1):
      letter = chr(lv)
      yield word+letter
```

Here is a test:

```
>>> print(list(mygenerator('jason')))
['jason', 'jasoo', 'jasop', 'jasoq', 'jasor', 'jasos', 'jasot', 'jasou', 'jasov', 'jasow', 'jasox', 'jasoy', 'jasoz', 'jaso', 'jasp', 'jasq', 'jasr', 'jass', 'jast', 'jasu', 'jasv', 'jasw', 'jasx', 'jasy', 'jasz', 'jas', 'jat', 'jau', 'jav', 'jaw', 'jax', 'jay', 'jaz', 'ja', 'jb', 'jc', 'jd', 'je', 'jf', 'jg', 'jh', 'ji', 'jj', 'jk', 'jl', 'jm', 'jn', 'jo', 'jp', 'jq', 'jr', 'js', 'jt', 'ju', 'jv', 'jw', 'jx', 'jy', 'jz', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

This implements most of the logic you requested.  I hope it helps illustrate how flexible and powerful python is.

Comment: @heybeethov, I'm not really sure what you mean.  However, if you take the code that I put in there and work with it I am sure you can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stab at your question using a filter function that consumes a generated list of words from your specification.

```
findall = lambda pred, word: filter(pred, words_gen(word)) 

def words_gen(word):
    yield word
    while True:
        lastchr = word[-1]
        if len(word) == 1 and lastchr == 'z':
            break

        new_lastchr = chr(97 + ((ord(lastchr) - 96) % 26))
        if lastchr == 'z':
            word = word[:-2] + new_lastchr
        else:
            word = word[:-1] + new_lastchr
        yield word


def check_match(it):
    def match(word):
        try:
            it.index(word)
        except ValueError:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    return match

lst = ['allena', 'allend','alphosis','alpinist', 'alternative']

> print(list(findall(check_match(lst), 'allena')))

['allena', 'allend']
```